# MVC EF5 Framework Initialize Database Error

Tags: entity-framework-5

I am using EF 5 and MVC 4.

After I first deploy the project (using web deploy) and the website is launched, my database is automatically created and I can see that the simplemembership tables are created. All my other tables are not. The simplemembership tables and my tables are combined into one DB. I did not use two separate DBs. This works fine in my development environment.

When I go to a controller that lists another table's data (not part of simplemembership) I receive the following error:

```
    [SqlException (0x80131904): There is already an object named 'UserProfile' in the database.]
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) +388
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose) +688
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady) +4403
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteNonQueryTds(String methodName, Boolean async, Int32 timeout) +2755286
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite) +527
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() +290
   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteSql(DbTransaction transaction, MigrationStatement migrationStatement) +247
   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteStatements(IEnumerable`1 migrationStatements) +202
   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorBase.ExecuteStatements(IEnumerable`1 migrationStatements) +19
   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ApplyMigration(DbMigration migration, DbMigration lastMigration) +472
   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Upgrade(IEnumerable`1 pendingMigrations, String targetMigrationId, String lastMigrationId) +175
   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorBase.Upgrade(IEnumerable`1 pendingMigrations, String targetMigrationId, String lastMigrationId) +19
   System.Data.Entity.MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion`2.InitializeDatabase(TContext context) +150
   System.Data.Entity.<>c__DisplayClass2`1.<SetInitializerInternal>b__0(DbContext c) +97
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.<>c__DisplayClass8.<PerformDatabaseInitialization>b__6() +23
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformInitializationAction(Action action) +66
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformDatabaseInitialization() +225
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.RetryAction`1.PerformAction(TInput input) +208
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeDatabaseAction(Action`1 action) +235
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type entityType) +36
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize() +71
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.GetEnumerator() +21
   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1.System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TResult>.GetEnumerator() +62
   System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection) +446
   System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList(IEnumerable`1 source) +80
   ProofPixModels.Controllers.SubscriberController.Index() in SubscriberController.cs:21
   lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +43
   System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) +248
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +39
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.InvokeSynchronousActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +15
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass8`1.<BeginSynchronous>b__7(IAsyncResult _) +15
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass39.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__33() +120
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4f.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronously>b__49() +452
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass37.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__36(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +15
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass2a.<BeginInvokeAction>b__20() +32
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass25.<BeginInvokeAction>b__22(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +230
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1d.<BeginExecuteCore>b__18(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +28
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +15
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +53
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +15
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +15
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass8.<BeginProcessRequest>b__3(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +42
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +15
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +14
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +606
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +288
```

There are obviously two InitializeDatabase commands going on here, but I cannot figure out why the clash over this one table. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Same as above, if you have already run an asp-net membership script table, you will need to clean this up by dropping all these other auto-gen tables.  Once you do that you can run the command update-database -verbose and you will see it create the UserProfile table no problem.

Answer (score 2):

I discovered that the problem was caused in the migrations file. One of my models included a collection of UserProfile(s) so this made EF create a Foreign Key which seems to force EF to write code to create the table. It is unaware that the simplemembership will do this for this table apparently.

Anyway I solved the problem by commenting out the create UserProfile table block in the migrations folder. I did make sure to replace it with an AddForeignKey method to keep the relationship intact.

Not sure this is the correct way, but it worked.

Comment: I have the same issue (and hopefully the same solution) -- but I see no foreign keys -- what foreign key did you add?  I see a primary key though -- For now, I'm just going to comment out the CreateTable/DropTable code in the Up()/Down() methods.

Answer (score 1):

This would also happen if you already have asp-net membership tables created earlier, which tries to prevent you from accidentally  loosing the credentials for all users.

Drop those tables and views and this error goes away.

Answer (score 0):

Had same issue then manually edited the Initialmigration script with drop table UserProfile at top and executed Update-Database -Verbose. Failed as there is n foreign key constraint.  Went to my local db deleted UserProfile table with all tables having foreign keys to that. Executed the migration and table created.